# How do I send SMS from PC to mobile using simplewire for Java?

Tags: java, sms

I am using "**simplewire**" library (for Java) which should be able to send SMS from PC to mobile. However, I am seeting the following error:

> Message was not sent! Error Code: 420
>   Error Description: Invalid Subscriber
>   ID or Subscriber Password.

Here is my code sample

```
import com.simplewire.sms.*;

public class send_text
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        SMS sms = new SMS();

        // Subscriber Settings
        sms.setSubscriberID("123-456-789-12345");
        sms.setSubscriberPassword("1234");

        // Message Settings
        sms.setMsgPin("+11005101234");
        sms.setMsgFrom("Demo");
        sms.setMsgCallback("+11005551212");
        sms.setMsgText("Hello World From Simplewire!");

        System.out.println("Sending message to Simplewire...");

        // Send Message
        sms.msgSend();

        // Check For Errors
        if(sms.isSuccess())
        {
            System.out.println("Message was sent!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Message was not sent!");
            System.out.println("Error Code: " + sms.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error Description: " + sms.getErrorDesc());
            System.out.println("Error Resolution: " + sms.getErrorResolution() + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know how to get Subscriber ID and Subscriber Password? Do I need an account for that?.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Simplewire Java SMS SDK Manual](http://www.afn.org/~afn48922/simplewire/sw-doc-manual-java-2.4.1.pdf)

> The subscriber ID is an ID number
>   provided to paid subscribers that
>   gives access to all of Simplewire’s
>   resources. The appropriate password
>   must also be set.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleWire is now [OpenMarket](http://www.openmarket.com/)

You would need to setup an account with OpenMarket to use their SDK.

They offer two types of accounts:

- Demo: which is where you could test your code on a short code that is for testing
- Commercial: This is where you would pay for a [Short Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_code) and access to their platform/service