# How can I send SMS from PC to mobile in scala?

Tags: scala, sms, sbt

I am working on a live project involving technologies like Scala, Akka and Slick. I have to implement the SMS functionality. After googling I didn't get a single example using Scala, but I got a few using Java and some comments saying that Simplewire is best to implement this functionality. But I am not able to find the library dependencies for any of them. Help me to resolve and implement this [simplewire](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4656996/3301316) example using Scala.

I tried to start like this,

```
import com.simplewire.sms._;            
object SMSHelper {
  def sendSMS = {
    val sms = new SMS() // SMS() is not resolving
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Are you using SBT? You should. Add Simplewire as a dependency in your SBT build script.

Comment: @Madoc...Yes! please tell me where can I get that dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Dependencies.html):

> Unmanaged dependencies work like this: add jars to `lib` and they will
>   be placed on the project classpath. Not much else to it!

Download the JAR file from [here](http://www.tucows.com/preview/221572/Simplewire-Java-SMS-Software-Development-Kit) and simply copy it into the `lib` folder located at the root of your SBT project then `sbt compile` and it should work.

If you want to place your libraries in another folder (for instance `custom_lib`), add this line to your `build.sbt` file :

```
unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "custom_lib"
```

Comment: You may have to do a `sbt reload` too.